# No such var: clojure.core/def

Tags: clojure

When I try to run this code in eclipse:

```
(ns cl1 
  (def s 1)
  (print s)
)
```

I get

```
java.lang.Exception: No such var: clojure.core/def (clojure.clj:1)
```

I'm a complete clojure newbie, but I think that the above code should create the symbol s, and then print what s is equivalent to to the screen (1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

def isn't used inside an ns declaration (ns is a macro, btw).  try this instead:

```
(ns cl1)

(def s 1)
(println s)
```

http://clojure.org/namespaces

Comment: Aha! I thought you had to enclose the whole file with the namespace.  This is the source of my confusion. Onward to learning!